# one item associated to a workflow Alfresco Activiti

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti

I would like to limit the number of files associated to a workflow to only one file and make the association mandatory. I've been trying to override bpm_package properties on my own workflow model and change the field properties in the share-config-custom.xml file but with no success.
I couldn't find any documentation online either.
Is it possible to do that? How?
Thx

Comment: I don't have the solution for you. But it could possibly be implemented with on update policy for workflow node I think. Or something similar.

Comment: This thread on the Alfresco forums may be useful: https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=45321

Comment: it's not what I was looking for. Ain't it possible to limit the default picker to pick just one file?? I use it with the selectone.ftl as in example by Jeff Potts, but the option doesn't seem to be accessible from the share-config-custom xml file